# How can I perform multivariable regression with neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, python, regression

I want to use a neural network to perform a multivariable regression, where my dataset contains multiple features, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. Every kind of tutorial on the internet seems to be either for a single feature without information on how to upgrade it to multiple, or results in a yes or a no when I need numeric predictions (that is, it uses neural networks for classification).

Can someone please recommend some kind of resource I can use to learn this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `sklearn`'s [sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html) class, which uses a multi-layer neural network to do regression. You first need to define the object `MLPRegressor`, for example, by specifying the value of the parameter `hidden_layer_sizes`, which determines the number of layers and the number of neurons per layer, then you should call the method [`fit`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.fit) on this created object and pass to it your data matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, where $n$ is the number of samples and $m$ is the number of features.